# get ID and display detail On Jtable

Tags: java, swing, file, jtable

i have a frame that contain a button and textfield.

my porpuse is read ID number frome textfield and when clicked on button, my table should display that ID with its name and mark.

my  "UserSearchFile.txt"  is this:

```
12 joe 120
14 ted 220
19 alex 560
22 julia 668
```

my jButton6ActionPerformed whole code is this:

```
int idS=Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
      final Vector data = new Vector();
      final Vector column = new Vector();
 File f=new File("D:\\UserSearchFile.txt");
    try{
    FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(fr);
    String s;
while ((s = br1.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] st = s.split(" ");
                String id = st[0];
                String name = st[1];
                String mark = st[2];
                if (id.equals(String.valueOf(idS))) {
try {
            String line2;
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\UserSearchFile.txt");
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
      StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br2.readLine(), " ");
              while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
               column.addElement(st1.nextToken());
                while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                       StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line2, " ");
                        while (st2.hasMoreTokens())
                                data.addElement(st2.nextToken());
                }
                br2.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(MainFrame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

 jTable1.setModel(new AbstractTableModel() {

        public int getRowCount() {
           return data.size() / getColumnCount();
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return column.size();
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return (String) data.elementAt((rowIndex * getColumnCount())
                        + columnIndex);
        }
    });
    jTable1.setVisible(true);
```

please help me and tell me how to write cleany and simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by using meaningful names for your variables and methods. `jTable1`, `br1`, `br2` and `jButton6ActionPerformed` are not acceptable names.

Then try to split a complex method into 2 or three operations, themselves split into 2 or three operations, etc. Each operation should be a method call. For example:

```
private void readButtonClicked() {
    String id = idTextField.getText();
    Student student = findStudentWithId(id);
    showStudentInGUI(student);
}

private Student findStudentWithId(String id) {
    List<String> lines = readLinesInFile();
    List<Student> students = transformLinesIntoStudents(lines);
    Student studentWithId = findStudentWithId(students, id);
}

private Student findStudentWithId(List<Student> students, String id) {
    for (Student student : students) {
        if (student.getId().equals(id)) {
            return student;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private List<Student> transformLinesIntoStudents(List<String> lines) {
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>(lines.size());
    for (String line : lines) {
        students.add(parseStudentLine(line);
    }
    return students;
}

...
```

Comment: You asked (sic) "how to write cleany and simple". My answer tells you how to transform the mess that your code is into clean, simple and readable code. What don't you understand?

Comment: i dont uderstand what is "private Student findStudentWithId(String id) " ?    
private List<Student> transformLinesIntoStudents(List<String> lines)

Comment: Your file contains lines, and each line represents a student having an ID, a name, and a mark, right? So, what your method is supposed to do is to find the student in the file that has the ID entered in the text field, right? `findStudentWithId(String id)` does that: it takes an ID as argument, finds the student with the given ID in the file, and returns it. Once you have found the student in the file, you just have to display its information in the GUI. That's what `showStudentInGUI(Student)` is supposed to do: it takes a Student object as argument, and shows the student name and mark.

Comment: oh yes, is possible to explain how display the search result(Such as id and name and mark) into table?   my code does not work!!

Comment: What is your table supposed to contain? Why use a table to display a single line?

Comment: how can i see this single line without a table? my project is about a library project(its my first project and i am new in java, about 15month).

Comment: It's up to you: two text fields, two labels, a single label containing a formatted String containing the name and the mark, whatever. But a table is normally used to display tabular data: multiple columns and multiple rows. Using it to display a single row is just... weird.

Comment: Oh thanks. thank you so much.very helpful. one ask: can i ask my every question about java with you, when i face them?

Comment: No. Ask them here, and wait for people to answer. Maybe it will be me, maybe other people.